# Scala: How to print a List in a Future

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

Look at the following code snippet:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main extends App {

  ids.foreach { l => println(l.mkString(", ")) }
  for(l <- ids) println(l.mkString(", "))

  def ids = Future(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
}
```

Method `ids` returns a `Future[List[Int]]` and I want to print the values of the returned `List`:

```
ids.map { l => println(l.mkString(", ")) } // prints nothing
for(l <- ids) println(l.mkString(", "))    // prints nothing
```

The problem is that none of the statements above prints the content of the `List` returned by `ids`. Am I missing something?

Comment: By mapping/flatMapping over a future, you're telling it what to do with the results *when* the results are available. If the program exists before they're available, then your map function will never be executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your statements aren't printing anything because your program is exiting before they run. If you wait for the `Future` to finish, you should see the values get printed out. See `scala.concurrent.Await.result`

E.g.

```
@ import scala.concurrent._, duration._, ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import scala.concurrent._, duration._, ExecutionContext.Implicits._
@ def ids = Future(List(1,2,3,4))
defined function ids
@ Await.result(ids.map(l => println(l.mkString(", "))), Duration.Inf)
1, 2, 3, 4
@
```